# Deployment with Django and Uwsgi

Tags: django, uwsgi

My problem is that uwsgi doesn't server static files of the django project. I am very new in web development and I was following this tutorial with uswgi deployment (https://uwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/Django_and_nginx.html)
I stuck on the stage when uwsgi run django. I was expecting that uwsgi will server static files after I ran:

`python manage.py collectstatic`

and then

`uwsgi --http :8000 --module myproject.wsgi`

But when I get on 127.0.0.1:8000 I see something like this 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DBHh3.png)

The structure of the project is trivial

```
--myproject:
-----myproject:
-------myproject:
----------init.py
----------settings.py
----------urls.py
----------wsgi.py
-------static
-------manage.py
-------db.sqlite3
-----venv
```

Thank you for any hint or help.

Comment: You might also want to check http://djangodeployment.com/2016/11/21/how-django-static-files-work-in-production/ for a schematic of how static files work. With uwsgi the idea is the same as for nginx or apache (because uwsgi is essentially a specialized web server); it's only the syntax that differs (the `--static-map`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to do this with uwsgi alone is to add the `static-map` parameter, i.e. `--static-map=/static=/path/to/my/proj/ect/static`.

(You'll want to do this for your `MEDIA_ROOT` too if you use it.)