# Django Deployment Server serving Static Files with only uWSGI

Tags: python, django, uwsgi

im trying to get my Django App to run using only uWSGI. The project is not that big, so i would really prefer to leave nginx out.

I just can't get uWSGI to show my static files though. I've gone through the settings multiple times and can't find the problem.

I have the STATIC_URL set to 'module/static/'
STATIC_ROOT set to '/module/static_files/' (i read somewhere that they should not be the same)

and my uwsgi.ini looks like this:

```
[uwsgi]
module=Module.wsgi:application
master=True
http=:80
processes=4
threads=2
static-map /static= /module/static_files/
```

the projects file structure is set up in the following way:

```
-- Project:
---init.py
---settings.py
---urls.py
---wsgi.py
-- Logs
-- module
---static
---static_files
---[... module template, model, urls etc]
-manage.py
-db.sqlite3
```

I can run collectstatic and generate all the static files in the correct folder.
But when i run the uwsgi script, it wont work and gives me a 404 file not found for all static files.

I would really appreciate any help, I've been stuck on this for an entire week now...

(i have checked out [Deployment with Django and Uwsgi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41676875/deployment-with-django-and-uwsgi)
but as far as i can tell, my static-map is set correctly)

Comment: I suspect you need the full path to the static directory.

Comment: @DanielRoseman thanks for your suggestion. The full path does not fix the problem either though

Answer (score 2):

you need to add your static files as static-map=/static=/module/static_files/