# Using static from /static folder from uwsgi when DEBUG is False

Tags: django, static, uwsgi

I have uwsgi and django.

Now I want to use `uwsgi` without `nginx`

So,I would like to use `static` from `uwsgi` even when DEBUG is false.

My static setting is like this ,and

```
STATIC_ROOT = 'static'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'frontend/dist'),
)

pytohn manage.py collectstatic.
```

Every static files are gathered under `static` folder.

Then I tryied some options to start `uwsgi`.

```
uwsgi --http :8008 --module myapp.wsgi --process=1 

uwsgi --http :8008 --module myapp.wsgi --process=1 --check-static=/static

uwsgi --http :8008 --module myapp.wsgi --process=1 --static-map=/static
```

However I can't load the images under static folder.

such as

```
https://www.myapp.com/static/defapp/test.img
```

There is a image under `/static/defapp/test.img`.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Deployment with Django and Uwsgi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41676875/deployment-with-django-and-uwsgi)

Comment: You are using `--static-map=/static` but that's not the proper syntax, you instead want to use `--static-map /static=/path/to/static` (You have to update `/path/to/static` obviously)

Comment: Ah, thankyou !! my --static-map was wrong, I will try this.

Answer (score 0):

**put this path for static**

```
import os
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
```

**insted of**

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'frontend/dist'),
)
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment, but I need to use `frontend/dist` for my webpack frontend.